# Unit test CountDocument with MongoDB mongo-driver in Go

Tags: mongodb, go

Currently I am trying to unit test a mongoDB adapter written in GO.
I use the mtest package of the mongo-driver.

I successfully handle Update, Find and so on but have a hard time creating a working mock response for CountDocuments.

I tried different Responses but always got  `invalid response from server, no 'n' field"`

I also can't find any good documentation about that.

```
func Test_Case(t *testing.T) {
    //DbInit before 
    ...
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run(mt.Name(), func(mt *mtest.T) {
        itemId := "item-id-to-count"

        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "foo.bar", mtest.FirstBatch, bson.D{
            {Key: "n", Value: bson.D{{Key: "Key", Value: "123"}}},
        }))

        memberCount, err := dbCollection.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": itemId}
        if err != nil {
            mt.Error("did not expect an error, got: ", err)
        }
        ...
    })
}
```

Can someone tell how the mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "...) should look like to make it work

Comment: You could do the following to run a test with mtest for `CountDocuments` function

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to run a test with mtest for `CountDocuments` function:

Suppose there is a repository like below:

```
type mongoRepo struct {
    client *mongo.Client
}

func (r *mongoRepo) Count(ctx context.Context) (int64, error) {
    collection := r.client.Database("test").Collection("restaurants")
    filter := bson.D{}

    return collection.CountDocuments(ctx, filter)
}
```

Then you can do the unit test using the `mtest` package as follows:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest"
)

func TestCount(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("count", func(mt *mtest.T) {
        defer func() {
            mt.Client = nil
        }()

        ctx := context.Background()
        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateSuccessResponse())
        // below code returns the count
        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "test.restaurants", mtest.FirstBatch, bson.D{{"n", 1}}))
        
        // For count to work, mongo needs an index. So we need to create that. Index view should contains a key. Value does not matter
        indexView := mt.Coll.Indexes()
        _, err := indexView.CreateOne(ctx, mongo.IndexModel{
            Keys: bson.D{{"x", 1}},
        })
        require.Nil(mt, err, "CreateOne error for index: %v", err)

        repo := &mongoRepo{client: mt.Client}
        count, err := repo.Count(ctx)
        require.Nil(mt, err, "Count error: %v", err)
        require.Equal(mt, int64(1), count, "expected count 1, got %v", count)
    })
}
```

Comment: Just the one CreateCursorResponse with the correct bson was all I needed, but maybe the code I'm exercising is different.